# Backpack 6 - repeatable with file upload field

Tags: laravel-backpack

In Backpack 6.5.1, i'm using a repeatable field with an upload file field using the backpack uploader.

```
        $this->crud->addField([   // repeatable
            'name'  => 'blocks',
            'label' => 'Downloads',
            'type'  => 'repeatable',
            'subfields' => [ 
                [
                    'name' => 'title',
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'description',
                    'type' => 'ckeditor'
                ],
                [
                    'name'      => 'file',
                    'label'     => 'File',
                    'type'      => 'upload',
                    'disk'     => 'public',
                    'withFiles'=> true,
                ],
            ],  
            'new_item_label'  => 'Add File',
            'reorder' => true,
            'init_rows' => 0,
            'min_rows' => 0,
            'tab'  => 'Files',
        ]);
```

and the model has cast the field to array

```
class Page extends BackpackPage
{
    use CrudTrait, RevisionableTrait;
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes, OpenPageLink;
    use Sluggable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'slug',
        'name',
        'title',
        'body',
        'blocks',
        'lists',
        'template',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'blocks' => 'array',
        'lists' => 'array',
    ];

    protected $fakeColumns = [
        'blocks',
        'lists',
    ];
```

The table field is type json and nullable.

```
id  bigint unsigned NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
slug    varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
name    varchar(50) NO      NULL    
title   varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
body    text    NO      NULL    
blocks  json    YES     NULL    
lists   json    YES     NULL    
template    varchar(50) YES     NULL    
created_at  timestamp   YES     NULL    
updated_at  timestamp   YES     NULL    
deleted_at  timestamp   YES     NULL
```

When I edit the model, I get a json encoding error.  If i remove the upload field from repeatable, it works fine.

[image]

Also, if I save the model with an uploaded file, I get a json encoding error.  If I remove the upload field type from repeatable, it works fine.

[image]

I have this working in other parts of the system, by using a relationship type and creating a related table for the downloads.  But wanted to store them as json for these files.

Any help would be great... thanks in advance.

cheers,

Rob

---

#### PHP VERSION:

PHP 8.1.14 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2023 01:53:44) (NTS)

#### LARAVEL VERSION:

10.40.0.0

#### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:

backpack/backupmanager: v5.0.0
backpack/basset: 1.2.2
backpack/crud: 6.5.1
backpack/generators: v4.0.2
backpack/logmanager: v5.0.1
backpack/medialibrary-uploaders: 1.0.3
backpack/menucrud: v4.0.1
backpack/newscrud: v5.0.0
backpack/pagemanager: 3.2.0
backpack/pro: 2.0.20
backpack/revise-operation: 2.0.0
backpack/settings: 3.1.0
backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.2.2
backpack/theme-coreuiv4: 1.1.1
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.2.0

Comment: Hello Rob. 

Not sure if relate but it might be, you are telling in your CrudController that `blocks` is a `fakeColumn`. 

I don't think that's the case, you have a `blocks` column in your table so it may help removing it from there. 

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @PedroX.... I've tried that, but it still gave the same errors.